# Program crashes at: (1) matrix multiplication; and (2) failed matrix addition/subtraction

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication, dynamic-memory-allocation

In short, I was assigned the task of creating a class that dynamically allocates memory to form a matrix of int values.

Part of the class are member functions that perform the basic matrix calculations -- addition, subtraction, and multiplication. Everything compiles (on my end at least), but when I used a driver to test the multiplication portion, it keeps crashing.

I'm using Codeblocks as my IDE and haven't had much luck with the debugger there in trying to figure it out. It appears that the calculation completes (with correct values), but then things go horribly wrong somewhere.

For clarity, each object of the Matrix class has the following member data:

```
private:
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int **element;
```

Below is a snippet of the implementation file in which the overloaded operator* is fleshed out. The portion where temp.element[i][x] is set to '0' before the loop performing the multiplication is commented out because the default constructor already sets all values to '0' -- which I had forgotten when I put it in originally. It didn't work when I didn't have it commented out either.

In testing, I used one 2x3 array and one 3x2 array.

```
Matrix Matrix::operator*(const Matrix &aMatrix) const
{
    if(cols == aMatrix.rows)
    {
        Matrix temp(rows, aMatrix.cols);
        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < aMatrix.cols; x++)
            {
                //temp.element[i][x] = 0;
                for(int n = 0; n < cols; n++)
                {
                    temp.element[i][x] += (element[i][n]
                                       * aMatrix.element[n][x]);
                }
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "Matrix multiplication failed -- incompatible matrix sizes."
             << endl;
        return *this;
    }
}
```

Upon trying to go through the code and find errors, I started re-checking the other functions I had. It appeared that both addition and subtraction worked, but the program would close if the matrices were incompatible (ie. trying to add a 2x3 and a 4x4).

Below is the snippet for the addition (subtraction is almost identical just '-' instead of '+' in the final loops.

```
Matrix Matrix::operator+(const Matrix &aMatrix) const
{
    if(rows == aMatrix.rows && cols == aMatrix.cols)
    {
        Matrix temp(rows, cols);
        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < cols; x++)
            {
                temp.element[i][x] = element[i][x] + aMatrix.element[i][x];
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "Undefined matrix addition -- matrices are different sizes."
             << endl;
        return *this;
    }
}
```

Any help or insight is appreciated. Thanks.

EDITED: Added overloaded assignment operator, copy constructor, and destructor code.

Below is the overloaded assignment operator:

```
Matrix Matrix::operator=(Matrix aMatrix)
{
    if(this != &aMatrix)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            delete [] element[i];
            element[i] = NULL;
        }
        delete [] element;
        rows = aMatrix.rows;
        cols = aMatrix.cols;
        element = new int* [rows];
        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            element[i] = new int [cols];
            for (int x = 0; x < cols; x++)
            {
                element[i][x] = aMatrix.element[i][x];
            }
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Below is the copy constructor:

```
Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix &aMatrix)
{
    rows = aMatrix.rows;
    cols = aMatrix.cols;
    element = new int* [rows];
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        element[i] = new int [cols];
        for (int x = 0; x < cols; x++)
        {
            element[i][x] = aMatrix.element[i][x];
        }
    }
}
```

Destructor:

```
Matrix::~Matrix()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        delete [] element[i];
        element[i] = NULL:
    }
    delete [] element;
    element = NULL;
}
```

Comment: how do you allocate the memory for `element` ? Shouldn't you check for the dimensions before doing any arithmetic ?

Comment: It's dynamically allocated in the default constructor. I tagged the question with dynamic memory allocation but didn't include that >_< -- didn't want to bog it down with too much code. To be more specific, it defaults to a 0x0 but accepts two arguments to define rows and columns respectively.

Comment: @uber08 - You are returning a Matrix by value.  That means we need to see your `Matrix` user-defined copy constructor, assignment operator, and destructor.  All of them play a huge role in the code you posted.

Comment: @uber08 - `Matrix Matrix::operator=(Matrix aMatrix)`  You're supposed to pass by const reference, not by value.  In addition, you're supposed to return a reference, not a brand new object.  There is a lot wrong with it, and would cause problems.

Comment: I can't imagine a good reason to return the lhs of an operation on an error condition. The client code is likely doomed to all sorts of miscalculations and corresponding error messages on standard error. As a practical matter, assuming that a library owns standard error can be painful for developers of a client. Perhaps they have specific ideas in mind for standard error. Perhaps they have it redirected to something like /dev/null.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks for all of your input. There may be something wrong with the prompt then. The prototypes given correspond to how I've written them :/. I'll try to implement your suggestions and worry about compliance later.

Comment: @uber08 - See my answer.  Please implement the functions properly first, then worry about the math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You posted a copy constructor and assignment operator.  Your assignment operator has 4 major issues:

1. You should pass the parameter by const reference, not by value.
2. You should return a reference to the current object, not a brand new object.
3. If `new` throws an exception during assignment, you've messed up your object by deleting the memory beforehand.
4. It is redundant.  The same code appears in your copy constructor.

You can rewrite the assignment operator in terms of the copy constructor and alleviate these issues:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
Matrix& Matrix::operator=(const Matrix& aMatrix)
{
    Matrix temp(aMatrix);
    swap(*this, temp);
    return *this;
}

void Matrix::swap(Matrix& left, Matrix& right)
{
   std::swap(left.rows, right.rows);
   std::swap(left.cols, right.cols);
   std::swap(left.element, right.element);
}
```

You just need to add the `swap` function to your Matrix class (probably as a `private`) function.

The code above uses the `copy/swap` idiom, and alleviates all of the issues I mentioned.  This will work provided that your copy constructor and destructor are written properly.  There are many threads on SO that talk about this idiom, but basically what is happening is this:

1. Create a temporary object from the passed-in object.  If there is a problem with `new` throwing, your `this` doesn't get messed up.
2. Swap out `this`'s members with the temporaries members.  This refreshes the `this` object with the temporary's data, and gives the temporary the old data we don't need any more.
3. Let the temporary die with the old stuff we gave it from `this`.
4. Return `this`.

As to the other aspects, if the two Matrices cannot be multiplied, then just throw an exception.  Do not return a bogus or confusing Matrix object that doesn't really reflect what happened.

In addition, you should first write operator `+=` and `*=`.  Why?  Because implementing operator `+` and `*` can be done in terms of `+=` and `*=`, respectively, plus you get the added bonus of having `+=` and `*=` available.

For example:

```
Matrix& Matrix::operator+=(const Matrix &aMatrix)
{
    if(rows != aMatrix.rows || cols != aMatrix.cols)
       throw SomeException;
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < cols; x++)
            element[i][x] += aMatrix.element[i][x];
    }
    return *this;
}

Matrix Matrix::operator+(const Matrix &aMatrix)
{
   Matrix temp(*this);
   temp += aMatrix;
   return temp;
}
```

So if the Matrix sizes are an issue, operator + and += will throw an exception.  Note how operator `+` is implemented in terms of `+=`.  Take the same approach to `*`, `*=`, and also `-` and `-=`.

Comment: Hmmm that all looks good. Thanks for all the help. Like I said above, I'll need to see what things I'm allowed to modify from what's been provided. That being said, your answer(s) would probably lead to a successful program if the suggested changes are allowed. Accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out what the syntax and semantics are of these operations. It looks from your example as though you want something like:

```
Matrix lhs = <something>;
Matrix rhs = <something>;
Matrix result = lhs * rhs;
```

to "just work". While this might be nice syntactically, you need to account for what happens if lhs and rhs can't be multiplied (or added, etc.) You also need to worry about setting up the result properly. You can't just return a "struct consisting of number of rows, columns and an array of pointers" and expect not to run into horrific memory management problems.

What will be responsible for making the product disappear? When it goes out of scope? C++ is not a very good language for linear algebra.

The first decision that you need to make is whether you intend to throw an exception for invalid operations, or return some indication of what went wrong, perhaps bool and a const char * to an error message.

Then you probably should try writing a function taking a result reference and 2 operand references, and just get the basic algebra right, if the matrices support the operation. (I have not mentioned yet that your Matrix is an integer matrix only.)

In "real life", you would probably try to find an open source standard solution that manages all of this, because numerical operations need to be managed very carefully.

One might even go so far as to suggest that this is a problem that has already been capably solved decades ago in Fortran, and to this day, if performance is an issue, there is a good chance that the underlying calculations might be in Fortran, or a library that was a port from C.

Comment: Thanks for looking it over. I was struggling over what happens to memory once the function is called and there is just this linger product... Unfortunately, I'm bound to this structure by the prototype provided to us. I'll see about your other suggestions.

Comment: @uber08 - As stated in the comment above, you need to first make sure that your Matrix objects have correct copy semantics.  So far we have absolutely no indication of that.